# CollectionView different sized cell origin.y is different from the cell beside it.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]
Presently my output is this but I need the layout to be little more organized.

I want the frame.origin.y for 1 and 2 cells to be the same as cell 0.

I have made section insets and min spacing all 0.

To brief it, I want the 1,2,3,4 cells to be adjusted in the first row.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: You need to use a different layout, look at the alternatives on github

Comment: So does the alignment happens automatically and can't we change the origin using the delegate methods?

Comment: Presumably you're using a stock flow layout currently?

Comment: It's the "flow" layout available with uicollectionview. Not sure what is stock flow layout. I am just changing the cell sizes in sizeForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: So yes, that's yhe way the flow layout works, you need to use a different layout.

Comment: oh ok, I get it. Any popular layout which I can try from github? It has so many that is confusing sometimes.

Comment: github quilt layout as your Google search

Comment: Thanks Wain. I am trying RFQuiltLayout.